# $f^{(2k)}(a)=0$. Does the Taylor series converge?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

If $f^{(2k)}(a)=0$ for all $k \in [0, \infty), k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then does the Taylor Series for f centered at $x=a$ converge for any value of x?

I picked an example where $f(x)=x, a=0$. Then Even-Power derivatives will always be 0. However, this function does not converge for all values of x. Does this constitute as a proper counterexample to the statement above?

Comment: Your function $f$ is a polynomial, and every polynomial is its own Taylor series (a finite sum) which is trivially convergent. So this does not disprove the statement.

Comment: Take a look at $f(x)=\frac{x}{1-x^2}$ around $x=0$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling at x=0 the function and its even power derivatives seem to be very different? None of them seem to be 0 so it doesn't seem to satisfy the conditions

Comment: @EG is there a valid counterexample? If this is true, how should I disprove it?

Comment: The function I suggested satisfies your condition that $f^{2k}(0)=0$ for each $k=0,1,2,\ldots$ and has Taylor series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n+1}$ which only converges for $x\in(-1,1)$. One way to see that even powered derivatives vanish at the origin is simply by nothing that the coefficients of the even powers of $x$ are all $0$.